# Connect to embedded AMQ from another process

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have an application which uses ActiveMQ broker. In order to have some integration test I have created another tool which puts messages into the queue.
What I want to achieve is to avoid using physical ActiveMQ but initialize AMQ together with starting my application, then connect my tool which loads messages into this queue and at the end close all connections. I can do sth like this using the same process (unit tests) when I start AMQ transport like vm://localhost but it doesn't work when I want to connect from another process to put sht onto the queue. Has anybody faced similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

The vm transport cannot communicate outside the JVM in which it was started.
Combining [peer](http://activemq.apache.org/peer-transport-reference.html) transport with `vm` allows for embedded brokers to discover remote brokers over [discovery](http://activemq.apache.org/discovery.html) networks (multicast, jgroups, etc), but this seems like overkill, suggest using `tcp` for simplicity.

```
//create embedded broker using tcp
BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
broker.start();

//remote client use tcp to connect, but local JVM client can use vm
vm:broker:(tcp://localhost:61616)
```

Comment: So, can I initialize connection like tcp://localhost:port without physically having run AMQ. Will it dynamically create broker to which I can connect from outside?

Comment: Yes, embedding a broker is not limited to `vm` transport; you can use `tcp`, see [this](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html). Local JVM clients can use `vm` transport to connect to embedded broker, while remote clients must use `tcp`, but it's the same broker to which they all connect; that's what you wanted, right?